# Bind DataTable to RDLC and ReportViewer

Tags: vb.net, datatable, datasource, reportviewer

I have read every single SO question and online article regarding this, and I get confused in a couple different instances.

As my project sits, I have tried to create a Report (`Report2.rdlc`) manually and drag different fields from `DataSources` onto the report, and use that report as the data source for the `ReportViewer`. This did not work. I *need* to use the `DataTable` I created from a `SqlDataAdapter`because it decrypts specific rows. I tried creating a `DataSet` and filling it with the `DataTable`, however I was unable to perform that, also.

1. I don't understand: if I have a `ReportViewer` control on a
   `WinForm`, what all I need in my code to bind a data source to it.
2. Is the code *even* creating a report and utilizing the report for
       the `ReportViewer`?

The `DataTable` name is `dt` and the `ReportViewer` control is `rv1`.

Here's the code I have been toying around with, however I am not sure what to put as the `Report Path`

```
    Dim RDS1 As ReportDataSource = New ReportDataSource("Test Report", dt)

    rv1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
    rv1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local
    rv1.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = True
    rv1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "Your Report Path"
    rv1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(RDS1)`.
```

The worst part is, the `ReportViewer` just shows up blank. There are no errors or any indicators as to what could be going wrong.

The information within the `DataTable` `dt` is all correct (verified by viewing it in a `DGV`). I am just trying to use that data in a `Report` / `ReportViewer`.

Does *anyone* have any advice? I cannot seem to catch a break on this issue.
Note: Exporting to Excel is not an option. There are encrypted values that require decryption. The report needs to be printable.

**Edit**: Here is how I populate the DataTable:

```
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        cmd.CommandText = "Select * FROM Participant " & _
                          "WHERE FIRST_NM_TXT = @searchFirst " & _
                          "OR LAST_NM_TXT = @searchLast"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchFirst", SearchFirstTxt.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchLast", SearchLastTxt.Text)

    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    adapter.Fill(dt)
```

So, here we have the DataTable with the correct data in it. I have then gone to the Project Name, Added a new Report (Report1.rdlc), and from here I am unsure of the next steps. If I create a DataSet dynamically, should I see it in this window?
[image]

---

### Since this seems to be a popular thread, I'll explain how I was able to do this in quick/easy steps.

1. Right click on your porject -> Add New Item -> Selection Report.rdlc
2. Top left (Data Source) -> New -> Dataset (select Database [Next ->] Dataset [Next ->] Your DB connection.
3. "Choose your database objects" screen -> Select Tables
4. "Choose the dataset" screen -> This will be reset at run time. **Make sure you remember the name of this Dataset, because it will be used in the code.**
5. Add ReportViewer control (under Reporting) to the form. Select reportviewer control and go to properties (bottom right pane in VS). Select Local Report's property and set ReportEmbeddedResource to point to the report path we just created. ** ProjectName.ReportName.rdlc**
6. Peform the usual:

   ```
   Public DataSet FillDS()
   //Try Catch block & other code omitted
   Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
   cmd.CommandText = "Select * FROM Participant " & _
                     "WHERE FIRST_NM_TXT = @searchFirst " & _
                     "OR LAST_NM_TXT = @searchLast"
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchFirst", SearchFirstTxt.Text)
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchLast", SearchLastTxt.Text)

   Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
   adapter.Fill(dt)
   ```

Then, we bind the datasource at run time.

```
DataSet yourDS = FillDS();
ReportDataSource rds = New ReportDataSource("YourDataSetNameFromStep4", yourDS.Tables[0]);
yourReportViewerName.localreport.datasources.clear();
yourReportViewerName.localreport.datasources.add(rds);
yourReportViewerName.refreshreport();
```

If there is something I could post in here to help anyone else, let me know.

Comment: Some things to check:
"Test Report" must be the name used in the report designer. It's case sensitive.
The dt must match the name used in the report designer too. I think you should be using a dataset rather than a table.
"Your report Path" should be of the form "namespace.reportname.rdlc" . It's case sensitive.

Comment: @peterG Thank you for replying! I have been stuck on this for a week. Let me explain a little bit more. So am I actually going to my project name, adding a report, and from there ???? Also, I am supposed to be dragging a ReportViewer control onto the form, correct? 
The problem I ran into when trying to use a DataSet, was that when I was creating the report, the DataSet I was dynamically creating was not in the object list. Thus, I did not even know for sure if my DataSet was working properly.

Comment: You have to start by getting the dataset into your data sources window. That defines the schema you will use. (You can use an ad-hoc query to populate it at runtime, with a WHERE clause built from options selected by the user)
Also your use of 'path' might indicate another bit of confusion: there are two ways to specify the report: either as a file, or as a resource. We're using the latter here.

Comment: @peterG Yes, that's EXACTLY what I am doing. ("using an ad-hoc query.."). That is my main confusion, and where I lack direction. If I were to provide more code, would you be able to further direct me? I am almost helpless at this juncture.

Comment: yeah fire away - add some code to your question

Comment: In fact give me a few mins and I will post some code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some things to check:
"Test Report" must be the name used in the report designer. It's case sensitive.
The dt must match the name used in the report designer too
"Your report Path" should be of the form "namespace.reportname.rdlc" . It's case sensitive.

EDIT:
The approach I normally use utilises an extra layer, in the form of a BindingSource as follows:
Fill a strongly-typed dataset using the ad-hoc query and a SqlDataAdapter.
Dim a Bindingsource and set its DataSource to the dataset and its DataMember to the table name.
Dim a ReportDataSource and set its name to the name used in the report designer, and its value to the BindingSource
eg

```
 Using cn As New SqlConnection(gcs)
        cn.Open()
        Dim sa As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, cn)
        sa.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = cGlobals.ReportTimeout
        sa.Fill(ds, "Foos")
    End Using
    bs.DataSource = ds
    bs.DataMember = "Foos"
    Dim rds As New ReportDataSource
    rds.Name = "dsFooList_Foos"
    rds.Value = bs
    rv1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds)

    Me.Show()
    rv1.RefreshReport()
```

Edit 2: At the point in your screenshot, drop down the datasources and pick the one you want. It will then appear in the Report Data window, which may be hiding in the 'View' menu (it's only there when you're working with a report) Then you can add a Table to the report from the toolbox, and then drag the fields from the Report Data window to the table cells.

Comment: I have a couple questions, do you think I can "edit" your answer and have you fill in the blanks? Thanks again.

Comment: Sure (I'm going to be AFK for a while tho)

Comment: This is going to sound ridiculous, but I am getting confused in our overlap. Am I supposed to keep my original code posted in the OP? Also, what do you mean by "strongly typed data set" ?

Comment: Oh right if you're not familiar with Strongly Typed datasets then we have a bit further to go. All the design-time support for reports in VS assumes you are using either strongly-typed datasets or objects - ie things that have properties. Sorry I can't give you a tutorial in ST datasets in an SO answer - you'll have to research on your own. But to start you off, go to the Data Sources window and click the 'Add New Datasource' sparkly cylinder icon.  It may be possible to bind a report to a weakly-typed dataset - I've never tried - but it's a lot easier to get started with the ST ones.

Comment: Okay, in my maze of attempts to figure out how to do this whole report thing, I have actually done this like 3-4 times. Never got it right, though. Will I be using the "Database" or an "Object" ? Since we are going to be using the ad-hoc query, I am not sure which to choose.

Comment: Database. But you have some way to go to get to reports. You need to get properly familiar with datasets and the designer first. And that's another whole bunch of SO questions right there!

Comment: I do know I have a ways to go, but I am just not familiar with the naming / proper procedures yet. I know that a DataSet is a collection DataTables. It's right where we are in this process that has really hindered my ability to get this task done. From choosing the Database Object in my dataset, assigning the dynamically created datatable to that dataset  and using it in the report / report viewer. Don't give up on me! I will learn it all

Comment: Start off by getting the designer and so on to work. Let it build the queries. Then move on to creating parameter queries in the designer. For reports, you can use join queries if necessary to combine results from multiple tables into one resultset. For queries that will also require updates, you should use multiple tables in the dataset, and populate them with queries that only refer to fields from one table in the select clause (you can still use a join). Best of luck

Comment: Right, right. I have DataSet1.xsd , with PARTICIPANT and PARTICIPANTTableAdapter (Fill, GetData()) which returns all values from the Participant table. I am going to need to decrypt some fields in the DataSet, and that leads me back to the DataTable. And here is where I am stuck

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47198/discussion-between-peterg-and-mark-larezza)

Comment: Hey peterG, go figure my work blocked the IM feature for SO. Can you send me what we talked about via email?

Comment: OK tell me your email address - or if you don't want to put it on here maybe try putting it in your profile and then you can delete it later

Comment: Um, no I can't - just the same as it was

Comment: There it is - sorry about that

Comment: OK got it now - you can delete it if you want

Comment: Okay - thanks. Have you ever run into errors when you create DataSet but receive errors on the TableAdapter.Fill ?

Answer (score 0):

something similar I have made for my "report loader", please check this link, it is written in C# but it will give you an idea how to do it.

[How to bind dynamically datasource to reportviewer on windows forms c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22017968/how-to-bind-dynamically-datasource-to-reportviewer-on-windows-forms-c-sharp)

Comment: Thanks, Dovla. Believe it or not, the only code I was missing was `CreateDataReader()`. Thanks for the source, though! It is good information.