# Report Viewer VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, report, reportviewer

I'm just trying to figure out how to use Report Viewer in VB.NET.

The report has only one text box with the data element name set to ReportName.

The code is simple.

```
    Private Sub frmCalibrationPreviewReport_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If _CalibrationReportID <> -1 Then
        With rvCalibrationReport
            .LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
            .ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessingMode.Local
            Dim tmpData As DataTable = modDeclare.SelectSQL("SELECT ReportName FROM tblReportTypes")
            .LocalReport.DataSources.Add(New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("tmpData", tmpData))
        End With
    End If

    Me.rvCalibrationReport.RefreshReport()
End Sub
```

Nothing is appearing on the report, it should contain two records.

Where am I going wrong?

Jim

Answer (score 0):

Here's a great article covering [Report Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252073.aspx)

I mention this link as it appears your new to this. I would recommend reading this first.

Comment: Thanks for that but walkthrough using SQL as its sample and not a data table.  I usually use DevExpress reports but I've never tried windows built in report. I can see why now!

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing

```
.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("tmpData", tmpData))
```

To

```
.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("tmpData", tmpData.defaultview))
```

I would also suggest looking at this question, very similar to yours...

[Bind DataTable to RDLC and ReportViewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21680733/bind-datatable-to-rdlc-and-reportviewer)

The problem with this question is there are a lot of gears at work when using reporting in visual studio. The problem could also be in the report file itself (`.RDLC`) if the field is not referencing the data source correctly. With the limited amount of information all I could suggest is using a working template and slowly adding your desired elements one at a time.

Comment: Hi, tried that didn't work :(.  

                Dim tmpData As DataTable = modDeclare.SelectSQL("SELECT ReportName FROM tblReportTypes")
                tmpData.TableName = "CalibrationReport"
                .LocalReport.DataSources.Add(New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("CalibrationReport", tmpData))
                .LocalReport.Refresh()
  
 Report's dataschema is set to CalibrationReport
 
 the textbox's data element name is set to ReportName
 
 That's all I've done to the report.

Comment: Jim when you post code, try not to post it in the comments section. Post it in your question with a title like "I tried this..." Its easier to read that way. Have you verified there are records in tmpData.TblReportTypes? at the time you fill it with `SELECT ReportName FROM tblReportTypes`